# why does this say "< must be escaped" in dreamweaver

Tags: html, dreamweaver

```
<div id="image" style="float:left;margin-left:15px;" >
<br>
<br>
<img src="https://pixabay.com/static/uploads/photo/2013/07/12/13/56/film-reel-147631__180.png"style="width:133px;height:133px;"  align="left"> 

  </div>
```

my question is why is this an error
ive tried getting rid of the"<" but that just doesn't work

Comment: which `<`? there's lots in your snippet, and nothing looks wrong with it, so probably you've got syntax somewhere EARLIER in your code.

Comment: for the line with img src

Comment: Try to close img tag : <img src="#" alt="" />

Comment: What on earth has C to do with that?

Comment: The last letter of "src" is "c"...

Comment: using "/" doesnt seem to work. it says special characters must be escaped i, so confused.

Comment: [mcve], preferably using jsfiddle.net

Answer (score 0):

Below is the proper HTML with commentary that passes validation:

```
<!-- You did not close the div tag here-->
<div id="image" style="float:left;margin-left:15px;"></div>
<!-- Changes to br tags -->
<br />
<br />
<!-- You were missing an alternate text tag and a closing tag and there was no space in front of the style tag -->
<img src="https://pixabay.com/static/uploads/photo/2013/07/12/13/56/film-reel-147631__180.png" style="width:133px;height:133px;" alt="Your description" align="left" />
<!-- You had one extra closing div tag here -->
```

Hint: You might want to read up on CSS and use that instead of inline styling.